# Notification not received after some time (10-25 min) in a terminated status - Flutter local notification

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-local-notification

I have an app that receives notifications in the foreground, background and terminated state.
but after some time (10-25 min) in a terminated  state if I send a notification the app has not received it and I'm sure I sent it because I save it in DB when everything is Ok and sent successfully

can anyone explain the problem?

Comment: how can we detect where is the problem if at least no code sample is added to the post?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: the problem is not in the code